# Creation of lists in blender python

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I'm trying to create a list box on a 3d view panel but I can't seem to find the correct control in the list of properties that have an associated UI or in any other related documentation.
What I'd like to do is instantiate on of these:
[image]
within a blender python script.
Does the API expose these controls and if not, is there some way of creating a custom control with its own drawing and mouse handling routine within python or would I have to add that in C++ and expose it to python (which is probably a bit more involved than I have time for at the moment)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help @Luther